# java servlet not found error 404 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I am using Eclipse 4.3 kepler on Ubuntu 14.04 and using Apache tomcat 7 , I have successfully created .jsp and .html files in my project but I cannot Run a servlet, I have all jar files added in library . I have read every article on this error 404 ,which I am getting when I launch the following servlet

```
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;




@WebServlet("/taxProcessor")
public class taxProcessor extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public taxProcessor() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s=request.getParameter("t1");
    int i=Integer.parseInt(s);
    String s1=request.getParameter("t2");
    int a=Integer.parseInt(s1);
    int t=0;
    if(i>=500000)
    {
        t=i*(30/100);
    }else if(i>=300000)
    {
        t=i*(20/100);
    }else if(i>=200000)
    {
        t=i*(10/100);
    }
    if(a>=60)
    {
        t=t-(i*(10/100));
    }
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.println("Thank you for Visiting");
out.println("Your Tax Laibality is"+t+"\n");
out.close();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

my web.xml file is

[image]

and all what I get is this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `web.servlets.newtax.taxProcessor.java` use `web.servlets.newtax.taxProcessor` in the web.xml

BTW your package name is `servlet` then how come you are giving `web.servlets.newtax` in the servlet-class tag

Example if in your eclipse your servlet class is in `src/somePackageName/ServletClassName` then your web.xml must contain the entries like this

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>anyName</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>somePackageName.ServletClassName</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>anyName</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/taxProcessor</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

One more thing as you specified the entries in the web.xml you can remove the annotation`@WebServlet("/taxProcessor")`

Finally run the servlet as `http://localhost:8080/YourProjectName/taxProcessor`

Comment: not helping I did the edits in web.xml but same thing is repeating

Comment: where does your servlet reside tell the path?

Comment: This is my full qualified name of servlet /newtax/src/servlet/taxProcessor.java

Comment: boss your businness codes should reside in src folder not servlet/newtax. what is the project name?

Comment: newtax is my project name

Comment: Ok so you are having your project newtax under the servlet folder if I am not wrong and servlet is the package name right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56586/discussion-between-creator-and-m-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml give /newtax/..../taxProcessor .Dont give /newtax/..../taxProcessor.java and Check from browser by giving the url `http://localhost:<port-number>/newtax.taxProcessor`. Here give port number to your tomcat server port.Default is 8080